# How to make CTRL-C work in command line when it does not?

Tags: bash, signals, sigint

I'm struggling with not working CTRL+C in a certain environment shell command line (CentOS 7 / Vagrant guest of Windows host). I use bash there.
The OS, seem, does not matter.

Example run `sleep 1000` and press the ctrl-c:

```
$ sleep 1000
^C^C^C
```

So, it's typing ^C and that's it.

`^C` is bound for the interruption.

```
$ stty -a
intr = ^C; ...
```

How to *make* it work?

In the following post, where I was inspired to fix it, the answer explains a lot but does not give a simple answer on how to make it work.
[Why didn't Ctrl-C work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92562/why-didnt-ctrl-c-work)
It seems it's a simple thing that I'm struggling with.

Comment: What  do you mean CTRL-C didn't work?  Are you running a binary from the command line?  Are you developing a script or prorgam and are asking how to trap the interrupt?  Please elaborate on exactly what isn't working and give us a use case so we can better help you.

Comment: @mikem No, just command line, shell. I use bash It does not work for interacting a running script nor when you type and hit ctrl-c and it resets you to a new line. So, just shell CLI. If you got some idea how to explain it better, feel free to edit, plz.

Comment: In my case Ctrl-Shift-C has become the way to stop a program.

Comment: I guess the problem is the same as trying to kill a program with `kill <PID>` you're trying to stop the program in an ordered manner. If you want to kill the program immediately you need to add -9 (the signal to stop a program immediately). You can test it pressing CTRL+Z, that will stop the process and get you back to the CLI prompt, you can then put the process in the background `bg <PID>` and then try to kill it, you will see you need the -9 or otherwise it will try to stop in an ordered manner and you will have to wait.

Comment: @YoMismo, yes, it is possible to choose "CTRL+Z" way but this is not what I needed. I needed to make CTRL+C work properly. It was working with the solution I found. You may give it a try if you have such issue too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [How can we set up a signal trap to be SIG_IGN and SIG_DFL in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447229/how-can-we-set-up-a-signal-trap-to-be-sig-ign-and-sig-dfl-in-bash) the simple solution is:

```
trap - INT
```

Just add this code into `~/.bashrc` for bash, for example.

I decided not to find the root of the cause but just fix it.

Another interesting post:
[Remove ^C when CTRL+C](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333766/remove-c-when-ctrlc)

Comment: Interesting.. bash reads the following files on startup:         /etc/profile
       ~/.bash_profile
       ~/.bashrc
       ~/.inputrc ... it this fixes smth similar for you, then my guess somewhere in there the INT trap gets unregistered there.

Comment: @user56452, yeah, I was playing with these files by cleaning them. The same. Maybe not all of them... But at least the solution overrides it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like maybe a key-mappιng problem.

At the shell prompt, type:

```
stty sane
```

and then try to use CTRL-C to stop a command.  If it still doesn't work, add the output from:

```
stty -a
```

to your question.  The `stty -a` command will list your current terminal line settings. The item of interest is called `intr`.  If `intr` is set incorrectly, CTRL-C won't work.

If `intr` is set incorrectly, you can try resetting it with:

```
stty intr CTRL-V-C
```

What that means is you type `stty intr`, then a space and then hold down the CTRL key and press <kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>c</kbd> with no spaces or or other characters between them.

After that, try to stop a command with CTRL-C again and see what the results are.

Comment: No, it's bind. I have `intr = ^C` after command `stty -a`. So, it's not about binding.

Comment: Can you stop any program with CTRL-C at all?  For example, if you run "sleep 10000", can you stop it with CTRL-C?

Comment: No, just mentioned this in the question. But it started working after the command in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not where I'm stuck.